# Then Convex Conjugate is Lower Semi Continuous

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, continuity, solution-verification, alternative-proof

Here is the definition of convex conjugates in Brezis:
[image]

My question is: How do we see that $f$ maps to $f(x) - \phi(x)$ is continuous? Here is my attempt of showing it and I wonder if this is correct:

For $x \in E$, let $\varphi_x: E^* \to (-\infty, \infty]$ be $\varphi_x(f) = f(x) - \varphi(x)$. Let $\epsilon > 0$, then
$$
|\varphi_x(f) - \varphi_x(g)| = |f(x) - g(x)| \leq (\| f \|_{E^*} - \| g \|_{E^*}) \| x \|_E \leq \| f - g \|_{E^*} \| x \|_E < \epsilon
$$
as long as $\delta = \frac{\epsilon}{\| x \|_E}$ such that $\| f - g \|_{E^*} < \delta$.

Comment: If depends on how continuity is defined, if $\phi(x) = +\infty$, then $\langle f, x \rangle - \phi(x)$ is $-\infty$ for all $f$. However, since the domain is non empty, you can ignore these $x$. I think the reasoning is a little sloppy.

Comment: @copper.hat I haven't thought this through then. How can we circumvent the issue of $-\infty$ as in your case? In this case since $E^*$ is always normed, we can make use of the usual metric space definition of continuity, right?

Comment: No, but it doesn't matter. You can replace the $\sup_x$ by $\sup_{x \in \operatorname{dom} f}$.

Comment: For any fixed $x \in E$, the function $f \mapsto \langle f, x \rangle - \phi(x)$ is an affine function (assuming that $\phi(x)$ is finite). And of course affine functions are continuous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would reason as follows,

Note that if $x \notin \operatorname{dom} \phi$ then $\phi(x) = +\infty$ and so $\langle f, x \rangle - \phi(x) = -\infty$. Since $\operatorname{dom} \phi$ is non empty, there is at least one $x^*$ for which $\phi(x^*)$ is real and so $\phi^*(f) \ge \langle f, x^* \rangle - \phi(x^*)$ and so we have $\phi^*(f) = \sup_{x \in E} \langle f, x \rangle - \phi(x) = \sup_{x \in \operatorname{dom} \phi} \langle f, x \rangle - \phi(x)$.

For each $x \in \operatorname{dom} f$ the map $g_x(f)= \langle f, x \rangle - \phi(x)$ is continuous (in $f$), affine and hence convex. The $\operatorname{epi} g_x$ is convex and closed.

Since $\operatorname{epi} \phi^* = \cap_{x \in \operatorname{dom} f} \operatorname{epi} g_x$ we see that $\operatorname{epi} \phi^*$ is convex and closed, and hence $\phi^*$ is lsc.